# How to pass control from $.post function to controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing an MVC application and have some problem with below code:

```
function create(box) {
       var box = dhtmlx.modalbox({
       title: "New PDF Document",
       text: "<div id='form_in_box'><div>Create a new PDF Documnet<hr /><label>Page Count:   <select name='pagecount'><option>1</option><option>2</option></select><label>Page Size:   <select><option>Letter</option><option>A4</option></select></label><span class='dhtmlx_button'><input type='button' value='Create' style='width: 86px' onclick='create_file(this)'></span><span class='dhtmlx_button'><input type='button' value='Cancel' onclick='close_file(this)' style='width:80px;'></span></label></div>",
       width: "300px"
       });  

function create_file(box) {
      $.post("/FileUpload/CreatePDFile.aspx");
```

Whenever user clicks on create button the "create PDF" page should get appeared. 
Above code works fine for cancel button but doesn't work for create button.

Comment: Do you get any errors?  Have you checked your browser's console and/or development tools window?  You are referencing jquery, right?

Comment: Also, you are missing the closing brace ( } ) for both the create and create_file functions.

Comment: i have included } in my code still it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery `post` function posts a form to the passed in URL (*through AJAX*), but does not redirect the browser to the new file.  You said ' the "create PDF" page **should get appeared**'.

The `post` function will NOT display the new page.

If you have to post form data back to the createPDFile.aspx file, you should wrap your input fields in a form.  Set the form action to your /FileUpload/CreatePDFile.aspx page, and submit the form (through the `$("#formname").submit()` function) in the create_file function.

See:  [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), [jQuery.submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Comment: Also, since this is an MVC app, are you actually going to a ASPX file, or are you going to a Controller action?  Your question indicates you are going to a Controller.

Comment: I know that it doesn't redirect the broser to the new page
in my view i have
 function create_file(box) {
      $.post("/FileUpload/CreatePDFile"); 
and in FileUpload controller i have
public ActionResult CreatePDFile()
        {
            return View("CreatePDFile");
        }